# Read a huge csv file and populate a Map in Javascript using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using `d3` to load a huge CSV file which I later use for some processing. I want to load the file and populate a `Map` based on certain conditions.

The csv file that I have is like this

```
h1    h2    h3    h4
1     A     3     4
2     A     1     6
1     B     5     7
2     C     8     19
```

and so on. There may be about 4M+ entries.

I want to populate a Map from this csv data. The map should be like this

```
1 A : [3, 4]
2 A : [1, 6]
1 B : [5, 7]
2 C : [8, 19]
```

The key must be the combination of `h1` and `h2`. Other columns are added as values.

I was able to achieve this using the following codes

```
function makeKey(a, b) {

    return "" + a + " " + b;
}

function csvToColumnArrays(csv) {

    let csvMap = new Map();

    for (let i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {


        let data = csv[i];

        let value = [];
        value.push(parseFloat(data["h3"]));
        value.push(parseFloat(data["h4"]));

        let key = makeKey(data["h1"], data["h2"]);

        csvMap.set(key, value);

    }

    return csvMap;

}




d3.csv(file_url, function(csv) {

    let csvMap = csvToMap(csv);

}
```

This was working perfect files of size 2M entries. But when the size is further increased, the page snaps.

Is there a more efficient way to do this.?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: I am running out of memory and page snaps

Comment: @rioV8 is there anything in the code that I can change to overcome this issue.?

Comment: try the code snippet below, it does not crash my computer, it will cost you a few MByte, but how much does your computer have. How big is the CSV file (byte count)

Comment: i have 32 GB Ram. the file size on disk is around 300 MB

Comment: unless you run a 32-bit OS it should all not be a problem, if you `console.log` before and after the conversion do you get these messages? Is there an error in the next 2M lines of the CSV, use binary search on row count to find the corrupt row.

Comment: There is no corrupt row, I have made sure.

Comment: I logged after each iteration in the for loop. The page snaps at different iteration each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a dictionary with 4M entries does not crash my computer.

```js
var count = 4 * 1000 * 1000;

var map = {}

for (var i=0; i < count; ++i) {
  map["" + i + "ABCDEF"[i%6] ] = [ Math.random(), Math.random() ];
}
//console.log(map);
console.log("done!");
```

With `new Map()`

```js
var count = 4 * 1000 * 1000;

var map = new Map();

for (var i=0; i < count; ++i) {
  map.set("" + i + "ABCDEF"[i%6], [ Math.random(), Math.random() ]);
}
//console.log(map);
console.log("done!");
```

Comment: These snippets are working fine. But my code is crashing. I think the issue is due to the fact the map requires n space and the csv array read by d3 is also taking n space. That makes error i guess. I monitored the Ram usage of the machine but it was merely 40%